# SQL - Calculating if an alphanumeric value exists in an alphanumeric range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a varchar column in a database and a requirement has come in so a user can enter a range to/from eg/ABC001 to ABC100

I have the following query but feel it might not be strict enough to work out if any values within that range exist.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable where MyColumn between 'ABC001' and 'ABC005'
```

I have a feeling an order by should be used or is there a better way to calculate the existence of values within a alphanumeric range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No orderby is required**.  That should be perfrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to boost that operation you can create a index on it.

Order by operation is done at the end of query execution, so the data will be retrived in the same way.

Comment: Create an index on what? MyColumn has an index if thats what you mean

Comment: I mean on "MyColumn". So as MyColumn already has index then this query is good.

Comment: Some indexes might not support the `<=` and `>=` operators. B-tree does.

Answer (score 0):

OP said:

> or is there a better way to calculate
>   the existence of values within a
>   alphanumeric range

The best way would be:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable where MyColumn>='ABC001' and MyColumn<='ABC005'
```

I find most people can't remember if `BETWEEN` includes or excludes the "end points".  By just always using `>=` and/or `>` and/or `<=` and/or `<` you have more clarity and flexibility.

Any `ORDER BY` would be applied to the resulting set of rows that meet the `WHERE` condition, and has nothing to do with the `WHERE` filtering.  You can use it if you want the final result set in a particular order, but it will have no effect on which rows are included in the results.